# How to change the selected numeric PivotFields function to `sum`

Tags: excel, vba

How to change the selected numeric PivotFields function to `sum` ?
Below code can't work. Maybe I should judge the field is selected and attribution is numeric first, but I don't know how the code should be.

```
Sub changeFunction()
Dim pf As PivotField
    For Each pf In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields
     With pf
       .Function = xlSum
     End With
    Next pf
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, but there is an issue.

When you cycle through all `PivotFields` using `For..Each..` - it will ignore items in the *Values* category.

To access those, you need to cycle through the `DataFields` instead, like so:

```
Sub changeFunction()
Dim pf As PivotField
    For Each pf In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataFields
     With pf
       .Function = xlSum
     End With
    Next pf
End Sub
```